Livewire2.6 need to swap tampates based on server event
I'm a beginner in Livewire, need to display one of the templates (the first with a Resend button if $waitTime <=0 and the second if $waitTime >0) according to server event updateWaitTime . In the way I implemented it, wire:click="getOTPCode(true)" doesn't work. What is a proper way to implement it?:
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end"
             x-data="otpSend()"
             x-init="init()"
        >
            
            <template x-if="getTime() <= 0">
                <button wire:click="getOTPCode(true)" type="button"
                        class="my-2 btn btn-primary rounded-pill text-white"><i
                        class="bi bi-arrow-counterclockwise"></i> Resend Code
                </button>
                <button hidden id="hide" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </template>
            <template x-if="getTime() > 0">
                <small>
                    Resend OTP in
                    <span x-text="formatTime(getTime())"></span>
                </small>
            </template>

</div>
    <script>
       document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {

            window.livewire.on('submitted', function () {
                resetForm();
                focusForm();
            })

            window.livewire.on('resent', function () {
                resetForm();
                focusForm();
            })

            window.livewire.on('updateWaitTime', function (wait_before_resend) {
                console.log(`updateWaitTime ${wait_before_resend}`);
                otpSend(wait_before_resend);
            })

            window.livewire.on('success', function () {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#hide').click();
                @this.emitSelf('reset')
                    ;
                }, 500)
            })
         
        

        })

        function otpSend(waitTime) {
            const milliseconds = waitTime * 1000 //60 seconds
            const currentDate = Date.now() + milliseconds
            var countDownTime = new Date(currentDate).getTime()
            let interval;
            return {
                countDown: milliseconds,
                countDownTimer: new Date(currentDate).getTime(),
                intervalID: null,
                init() {
                    if (!this.intervalID) {
                        this.intervalID = setInterval(() => {
                            this.countDown = this.countDownTimer - new Date().getTime();
                            
                            
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                },
                getTime() {
                    if (this.countDown < 0) {
                        this.clearTimer()
                    }
                    return this.countDown;
                },
                formatTime(num) {
                    var date = new Date(num);
                    return new Date(this.countDown).toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {
                        minute: '2-digit',
                        second: '2-digit'
                    });
                },
                clearTimer() {
                    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <?php
    public function getOTPCode($resend = false)
    {
        $this->emit('updateWaitTime', $this->wait_before_resend);
    }
    ?>

